# Get info from php extension

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick, php-extension

I am using php extension imagick. I want to use parts of it based on the condition if the file format is supported. I can see the info's about the extension using `ReflextionExtension()` like this:

```
$imagemagick = new ReflectionExtension('imagick');
$imagemagick ->info();
```

It renders something like this in the browserwindow:
[image]

How to get the **supported formats as an array?**

`var_dump()` and `print_r()` don't reveal much. This is the result of a `var_dump()`:

```
object(ReflectionExtension)#1 (1) { ["name"]=> string(7) "imagick" }
```

I want to add some code inside a logic that is only excecuted `if (JP2)` is supported. So I need to get the array of formats to check for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can grab that list with `Imagick::queryFormats('*');`.

As you're looking for `JP2` support, than you may be able to call something like this...

```php
if (!empty(Imagick::queryFormats('JP2'))) {
```